# No libraries were linked as Runtime Shared Libraries (RSLs)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

I am create a flash application for the chatting purpose and every thing going on perfect but there is only one warning when i use to publish. The warning is thrown as i subjected the title i.e.
"No libraries were linked as Runtime Shared Libraries (RSLs) because of your publish settings: Export SWC"

I am checked the option of export as SWC in publish setting but i need to export it as SWC without throwing any warning.
So please suggest me that how this warning can be overcome.

Comment: This warning is simply to let you know that you could take advantage of RSLs and you aren't there's no reason you need to heed it, if you'd like I'm sure there's a compiler argument to suppress the warning but it's the same as if you just personally ignore it.  A runtime shared library is used to load classes/bytecode at run-time it allows this stuff to be cached and for just the app code to be loaded if it changes but the framework doesn't.  Not using it means the classes from swcs you depend on are compiled into your swf/swc directly.

Comment: So, can you tell me the solution of this warning because i am using a preloader which i have configured on action script Setting dialog box. My preloader is not working out so plz tell me the solution.

Comment: verify that you are running the debug version of flash in the browser your using to view your project if not install it before trying anything else, go here and scroll to the bottom of the page http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/find-version-flash-player.html  in chrome it has a built in flash player that overrides whatever you install unless you explicitly disable the built in plugin within the chrome settings, I'm not sure if something similar is true in Safari (they are somewhat similar with WebKit for HTML rendering)

Comment: You are probably getting some sort of run-time error, if you don't get any error at run-time and you have the debug player installed in the environment your testing with and it appears to just not run I would check the developer tools in the browser for any sort of javascript errors or something of the sort (generally you'll find something, there are rare occasions like parsing XML that has gone bad that can cause errors that are just swallowed and don't surface in any way but I've rarely encountered these)

Comment: I didn't got any solution can you please illustrate me the point to be perform on overcoming this warning.

Comment: The warning itself is unrelated to the problem your experiencing, can you post either an example of this running or some code/screenshots of your setup that give some way to reproduce the problem, if not I don't think anyone can help.

Comment: Actually i am using MVC Express framework with the flash cs6 and i have changed the export settings i.e. Eport SWC. This setting is mandatory to use the framework. But as i deselect the Export SWC Option the RSL Preloader works fine but as i selected the Export SWC Option on the publish setting. the preloader stops working and display a warning as i subjected above.

Answer (score 1):

You see this warning when publishing because you're using a Runtime Shared Library somewhere in your project, but you aren't taking advantage of it because SWCs get compiled into your code instead of loaded at runtime. You can safely ignore this warning, although it is annoying.

I saw this warning when I was accidentally using TLF text instead of Classic text for one of my text fields. This happens when you import text fields from Illustrator. When I changed it to Classic text, this publish warning went away. TLF adds new features and flexibility to text fields, but can be buggy especially with mobile AIR projects.